# What does "Team Biddy" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

In the recent episode of the "Grey's Anatomy" (S13E05), Meredith (one of the female characters) says to a fellow doctor:

> Don't say that to Baily, because she's full-on Team Biddy.

I want to know what does *Team Biddy* mean?

Comment: FWIW, "biddy" is also an old term for a pet chicken.

Answer (score 1):

**Biddy:** (*noun*) A woman, especially an older one who is...talkative. (YourDictionary)

Thus the OP's reference to a *"full on* ***Team Biddy***" merely informs the reader that the two ladies are female doctors who are discussing something concerning a third-party named Baily. It is likely (inferred) that all three are mature in age, experienced and cable of working well together as committed ("*full on*") members of a team -- Team Biddy.

Comment: Curious to know if capital "T" & "B" in "Team Biddy" are the OP's constructs or not.  OP's confirmation one way or the other might help me to add something to my answer above.

Comment: Meredith (the ‘Grey’ of _Grey’s Anatomy_) isn't really old enough to be a biddy herself. Rather, I would think she is saying that Baily (whom I don't know) is a real gossip, and that it wouldn't be wise for the person Meredith is talking to to reveal the topic of their conversation to Baily.

Comment: @PeterPoint I took the line from the subtitle. I can't guarantee its correctness.

Answer (score 0):

OED gives a def. for "biddy"as talkative AND interfering, thus, pejorative idiom for "busy body" with the usually added quality of older age. The combination with "team" in this instance is plain. Every team seems to have one, at least metaphorically, if not literally.

Comment: It suddenly occurred to me that these three "biddies" may have a nice line in self-deprecation and may have given themselves the tongue-in-cheek title of Team Biddy.  This being the case they may not be mature in age at all, and perhaps even less likely to be talkative or interfering. Just a thought.